# How to check if your message had been seen in Pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

In official Telegram client if message had been seen there are two ticks. Is there an alternative in Pyrogram? There isn't a property for it in `Chat`, `Dialog` or `Message`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Those ticks show message state (received/read) do you want to read them?

Comment: @A.Albershteyn Yes

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Message

`views` (int, optional) – Channel post views.

Comment: This property is optional and isn't present in personal messages, only in channel posts. In official client it is an eye icon and number, not ticks.